# External table columns are not populated when I run the query "SELECT ddl FROM projectName.datasetName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;"

Tags: google-bigquery

External table columns are not populated when I run the below query
"SELECT ddl FROM projectName.datasetName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;"

Earlier I could see this External table columns properly in the DDL which was given by above query. But now I can't see any columns. Please confirm me whether it is a bug?
If yes, please let me know when Can I expect this fix?

Thanks in Advance,
Srinivas

I tried running below query with proper project name and dataset name
SELECT ddl FROM ..INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're experiencing an issue where the columns of your external table are not being populated when querying **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**. This could be due to various reasons, such as changes in configurations, updates to the system, or potential bugs.

According on the internal documentation, a bug was filed in the issue tracker and has been resolved. In your use case, if it's a bug, the fix would depend on the system or service you're using. If you're using a specific database or platform (like Google BigQuery, Amazon Redshift, etc.), I would recommend checking their official documentation or support channels for any reported issues or planned fixes. Generally, bug fixes are rolled out in updates, but the timeframe can vary depending on the severity of the issue and the development cycle of the service provider.

While waiting for a fix, you might consider alternative methods to retrieve the column information for your external table. For example, you could try querying the specific table directly `(SELECT \* FROM projectName.datasetName.externalTableName LIMIT 0)` to see the table structure. Additionally, you could check if there are any other metadata tables/views available in your environment that might provide the necessary information.

If you suspect it's a bug and you can't find a workaround, reaching out to the support channels of the platform you're using would be a good step. They can provide more specific assistance and potentially escalate the issue for investigation.

Remember to provide as much detail as possible when reporting the issue, including specific versions, configurations, and any recent changes made to your environment, to help expedite the resolution process.